# My PHP echo at the top of the page

Tags: php, codeigniter, buffer, echo

I'm using Codeigniter, and have defined my own controller who contain my layout

```
protected $layout = 'layout';
protected function render($content) {
  $view_data = array(
    'content' => $content
  );
  $this->load->view($this->layout,$view_data);
}
```

all controllers extends this one on define their own content by calling a View

```
class Voyage extends My_Controller {
    function index(){
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $content = $this->load->view('admin\voyages');
        $this->render($content);
    }
```

My html page is like this:

```
<body>
<header>.....</header>
<nav>......</nav>
<section>.. <?php echo $content; ?>...</sectiont>
```

The problem is that my echo $content is putting the content at the top of the page before header et nav elements.

Can you help me with this?

Comment: Seems like a classic cache issue. Try disabling cache during development, or at least empty it and/or force reload your page.

Comment: Besides that; I had an issue a while back too where it seemed CodeIgniter will stack up all `load-view()` calls, sometimes triggering wrongly arranged outputs. In my case it suddenly got resolved on it's own (I think emptied cachce too). Otherwise it might be that CodeIgniter has issues grabbing `load->view()`'s from different classes in one controller-call.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't something with CSS e.g. `float: left` or something? Btw. could you post `voyages.php` and `layout.php` content?

Answer (score 3):

```
$content = $this->load->view('admin\voyages');
```

should be:

```
$content = $this->load->view('admin\voyages', '', true);
```

if you want to load it into a variable. what you are doing renders it immediately